# Solutionfile .sln is the changedate the creationdate?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, solution

I've got a little project im coding.

And i didn't document the date i started it.

Can i be sure that the **date of change** of the solution file (.sln) is the **creationdate**?

Or do the solutionfile change while developing?

And if yes , when?

Or is there a other way i can read this in `Visual Studio 2010`,
e.g. at the properties of that project?

Comment: You probably cant rely on it. If you add projects to the solution it would change, there maybe other reasons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't be sure if the **date of change** is the creation data as with each file.

E.g if you add projects to your solution and save it, the date of change, is changed. But i think if you go to the files properties there is a creation date.

Comment: jeah i just recognized it .. you mean the files properties in windows right??
the creation date there is later then the last changed date xD,
i think its because of coping the file from diffrent devices...

Comment: I meant the files properties yes. Do you manage you project with any source control?

Comment: No, i dont .. because it was just a private project just for fun. I think ill go for the last change date .. i think its accurate enough...